# Как создать свой формат даты в SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы на вход приходило время (02:30), а на выходе были минуты (150). Реализована штука, которая делает наоборот, минуты (90) в формат чч:мм (01:30)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");

try {
   Date dt = sdf.parse("90");
   sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
   System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date, dateZero;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("02:30");
        dateZero = sdf.parse("00:00");
        long different = date.getTime() - dateZero.getTime();
        System.out.println(different/60000);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить следующее решение:

```
private static long getMinutes(String value) {
    String[] tokens = value.split(":");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    return TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours) + minutes;
}
```

Использование:

```
System.out.println(getMinutes("02:30") == 150);
```

Результат:

> true

Comment: а без TimeUnit можно как-то сделать?

Comment: конечно, умножайте на 60, прост с `TimeUnit` кажется нагляднее